# Getting every key entry in nested map

Tags: json, flutter, dictionary, dart

I have a nested map like the following:

> {    "name":"Italien",    "documentId":a4c3jzNeYIaz3MrPWh1c,
> "children":[
> {
> "name":"Lombardei",        ],
> "documentId":XM0SBotZiL7YwCWVptaF,
> "children":[
> {
> "name":"Brescia",
> "documentId":Cb6NMCTCs5kbdjbmlpyO,
> "children":[
> {
> "name":"Nave",
> "documentId":2cZuhJjRHejA1ztPr2iS,
> "children":[
> ]
> },
> ]
> },
> ]
> },   ] }

this could go on forever. So I need to get every value for documentId, even in deep nested children. I cannot call the keys explicitly because the map is always dynamic and changes over time.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you want. Can you write what result you want given the input from your example.

Comment: in the end I just want to have a single Map with that looks like this: { 'documentId' : 'a4c3jzNeYIaz3MrPWh1c', 'documentId' : ' XM0SBotZiL7YwCWVptaF' , 'documentId' : 'Cb6NMCTCs5kbdjbmlpyO' , 'documentId' : '2cZuhJjRHejA1ztPr2iS' }

Comment: Maps does not support multiple entries with the same key.

Comment: Alright, then just a List<String> containing all the the mentioned documentIds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion like this:

```
handleMap(Map map, [String key]) {
  map.foreach((key, value) {
  
    if (value is Map) handleMap(value, key);
    else if (value is List) handleList(value, key);
    else handleValue(value, key);
  });
}

handleList(List list, [String key]) {
  list.foreach((entry) {
    
    if (entry is Map) handleMap(entry);
    else if (entry is List) handleList(entry);
    else handleValue(entry);
  });
}

handleValue(dynamic value, [String key]) {
  ...
}
```

Call it with:

```
handleMap(data);
```

Comment: glad to hear that! Please make sure to mark this question as answered :)